# How to retrieve all set cookies into browser tab angular

Tags: angular, cookies

I need to retrieve all the cookies which are showing on my URL .

```
const allCookies = this.cookieService.getAll();
console.log('allcookies',allCookies);
```

Please find the attached screenshot in which I want to get all cookies from `google.com`,`localhost` and from other providers (if any exists there).

But first, I would like to know if it is possible or not ?

[Cookies-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKgGH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

> In the Constructor of your service

```
constructor(
    @Inject( DOCUMENT ) private document: any,
    @Inject( PLATFORM_ID ) private platformId: InjectionToken<Object>,
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser( this.platformId );
  }
```

> and then a method like

```
 getAll(): {} {

if (!this.isBrowser) {
return;
}
    const _cookies: {} = {};

    if ( this.document.cookie) {
      const splittedCookies: string[] = this.document.cookie.split(';');

      for ( let i = 0; i < splittedCookies.length; i++ ) {
        const cookies: string[] = splittedCookies[ i ].split('=');

        cookies[ 0 ] = cookies[ 0 ].replace( /^ /, '' );
        _cookies[ decodeURIComponent( cookies[ 0 ] ) ] = decodeURIComponent( cookies[ 1 ] );
      }
    }

    return _cookies;
  }
```

Comment: thanks algdb for your support and quick answer , but i want to retrieve all cookies data as per attached screenshot .

Comment: could u help me for that ?

Comment: I don't understand for the pic what you are tring to achive

Comment: ok, you simply cannot access google cookies, or any other cookie that has not been set from your domain. The browser will not let you do this for security reasons, moreover, if you set the cookie as HTTP Only no Javascript can access it